Is biblical meditation literally saying the word of God out loud?
I’ve always wondered what it meant to meditate on the word. Then I noticed that the words translated to meditation in Hebrew always has some connotations to utterance or speaking or some sound. Instances below:
hāḡûṯ = meditation, utterance, musing
higāyôn = meditation, resounding music, musing, resounding music meditation, plotting
hāḡâ = to moan, growl, utter, muse, mutter, meditate, devise, plot, speak, to roar, growl, groan, to utter, speak, to, meditate, devise, muse, imagine, to utter, to mutter
Even in the Septuagint the word for meditate is μελετήσει and one of its meanings is “used of the Greeks of the meditative pondering and the practice of orators and rhetoricians”.
This has made me think: is a form of meditation literally just saying the word of God out loud and in our hearts (which God can hear)?

I can't find anything in scripture that calls for people to pray, speak in silence. Although it does say to do it secretly, it does not ever say silently. The only thing that I can find is waiting on God in silence. All instances in OT and NT people are vocal to God. In our study and contemplation of the word, the Spirit guides us, and it makes sense that our thoughts would be vocal to the Spirit in dialogue, even though he whispers to us.

It means to think about what it is telling you. To think about how you will apply it.

Psalm 19:14

Let the words of my mouth and the meditation of my heart be acceptable
in Thy sight, O Lord, my Strength and my Redeemer.

Commentators such as Rashi believe that this verse teaches us that when "meditation" is mentioned, it is a matter of heart as well as mind: "Every expression of הגה refers to the heart, as you say (Psalm  19:15): “and the meditation (והגיון) of my heart.”
Moreover, meditating on God's word results in practicing it and delighting in it.  Psalm 1:

1 Blessed is the man
who walks not in the counsel of the wicked, nor stands in the way of sinners,
nor sits in the seat of scoffers; 2 but his delight is in the law [or teaching ] of the Lord,
and on his law he meditates day and night.

As Psalm 1 indicates, there must be a union of theory and practice. It is not enough to recite the Word (either out loud or silently). The one who truly meditates on the law also rejects the temptations of the wicked. Rashi thinks  that "his law" here means that, for the man of spiritual integrity, the Word no longer belongs exclusively  to the Lord but is also the righteous man's property.

In the beginning, it is called the law of the Lord, and after he has
toiled to master it, it is called his own Torah.

Rashi may be overstating the case. However we need not agree with his interpretation literally to understand that "meditating" on God's word means more than simply reciting it. When one reads with one's whole heart and mind, the external word/law becomes internalized:
Jeremiah 31:33

For this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel
after those days, declares the Lord: I will put my law within them,
and I will write it on their hearts. And I will be their God, and they
shall be my people.

